# How to change the linux environment-variables

Tags: linux, environment-variables

When I use this command in Linux

```bash
systemctl --user show-environment
```

After one option is listed, how can I change it with command or find relevant configuration files？

Answer (score 1):

Add user environment variables to `$HOME/.profile`.

```
export SOME_VALUE=the-value
```

For system wide changes look at `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile.d/`.

Answer (score 0):

From `man systemctl`:

> Environment Commands
> systemd supports an environment block that is passed to processes the manager spawns. The names of the variables can contain
> ASCII letters,
> digits, and the underscore character. Variable names cannot be empty or start with a digit. In variable values, most characters are
> allowed, but
> the whole sequence must be valid UTF-8. (Note that control characters like newline (NL), tab (TAB), or the escape character
> (ESC), are valid
> ASCII and thus valid UTF-8). The total length of the environment block is limited to _SC_ARG_MAX value defined by
> sysconf(3).
>
> ```
>    show-environment
> ```
>
> Dump the systemd manager environment block. This is the environment block that is passed to all processes the manager spawns.
> The
> environment block will be dumped in straightforward form suitable for sourcing into most shells. If no special characters or
> whitespace is
> present in the variable values, no escaping is performed, and the assignments have the form "VARIABLE=value". If whitespace or
> characters
> which have special meaning to the shell are present, dollar-single-quote escaping is used, and assignments have the form
> "VARIABLE=$'value'". This syntax is known to be supported by bash(1), zsh(1), ksh(1), and busybox(1)'s ash(1), but not dash(1)
> or fish(1).
>
> ```
>    set-environment VARIABLE=VALUE...
> ```
>
> Set one or more systemd manager environment variables, as specified on the command line. This command will fail if variable
> names and values
> do not conform to the rules listed above.

Comment: Hi,I tried it, but it reverted when restarting

Comment: I also tried using this command: unset-environment. it doesn't work,i don't know what happened